# tmux visual indication if panes are synchronized

Tags: tmux

Is it possible for tmux to have some visual indicator if synchronized-panes is enabled for the window?

Perhaps the status bar changes to blue, or just a star appears somewhere?

I often set synchronized-panes, leave for a few hours, and come back to forget if it's enabled or not.

Answer (score 17):

The `pane_synchronized` format variable can be used with conditional formatting to adjust bits of the various format-using status options.

You could add  `SYNC!!!` in a blue background to the end of `status-right`:

```
set-option -ag status-right '#{?pane_synchronized, #[bg=blue]SYNC!!!#[default],}'
```

Or you could add blue asterisks around the entry in the window list:

```
set-option -gw window-status-current-format '#{?pane_synchronized,#[fg=blue]***#[default],}#I:#W#F#{?pane_synchronized,#[fg=blue]***#[default],}'
```

(the `#I:#W#F` in the middle is the default format)

You might also want to adjust `window-status-format` if you want to know when an inactive window’s panes are synchronized.

Comment: Thank you for the tips! I combined it with unicode characters to produce the following window labels: `" #{?pane_synchronized,⛓ , }#W "`.

Comment: went with a little more bloated solution, and FWR my  thinks ‍♀️ when thinking about the word *synchronize* ‍♂️


_# styles for windows
## styles for current active window_

`setw -g window-status-current-format "#[fg=#000000]#[bg=colour208] #I:#W#{?window_zoomed_flag,,}#{?pane_synchronized,‍♀️‍♀️,}"`

_## styles for inactive windows, ie. background windows_

`setw -g window-status-format "#I:#W#{?window_zoomed_flag,,},#{?pane_synchronized,‍♀️‍♀️,}"`


And yeah the mag lens looks like a ping pong paddle ...gotta work on that one.

Answer (score 1):

These are the lines from my tmux.conf which turn pane sync on and off. In the commands I also set the color of the status bar.

```
bind C-y set-window-option synchronize-panes on \; set-window-option status-bg red \; display-message "Panes synchronized."
bind C-u set-window-option synchronize-panes off \; set-window-option status-bg green \; display-message "Panes un-synchronized."
```

This is an incomplete solution for me, because when I switch to another window where panes are not sync, the status bar stays red.

Answer (score 0):

here's what I use in my config:

```
set -g status-left " #[fg=white,bold][#h] #{?pane_synchronized,#[fg=green]SYNC ,#[fg=yellow]SYNC }"
```

It'll display the hostname on the left side of the status bar, then the word "SYNC" in green if it's synchronized and yellow if not.